# Draw a figure by using ``bar'' with individual colors

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

[image: An Example]

I want to draw a picture in MATLAB like this.

Please see the following [codes in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/476496-how-could-i-set-the-legend-for-a-particular-bar-in-a-bar-chart).

```
y = [2 2 3; 2 5 6; 2 8 9; 2 11 12];

h = bar(y);  

set(h, {'DisplayName'}, {'Jan','Feb','Mar'}')  % MATLAB tells me there is error here.

legend()
```

[image: Example]

However, the colors for `{'Jan','Feb','Mar'}` are assigned automatically. Can I use the indivual colors? For example, red for 'Jan', blue for 'Feb', and yellow for 'Mar'.

Comment: What do you mean by "MATLAB tells me there is error here"? What specifically is the error?

Comment: I suspect that you should be able to use the command `set(h,{'color'},{'red','blue','yellow'})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the code
set(h, {'DisplayName'}, {'Jan','Feb','Mar'}')
is correct. The single quotation mark after Mar'} is necessary. If we delete it, MATLAB cannot perform well.

For using individual color, just use
set(h(1),'Facecolor','r')